# Volumes of Hecke operators

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, haar-measure, hecke-operators

Let $G=GL(2, F)$ and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup. Unramified Hecke operators are defined by the action of the double cosets
$$T(n) = \bigcup_{\substack{ad=n, a>0 \\ a|d}} K \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & \\ & d \end{array} \right) K$$

There is a decomposition in right cosets
$$\bigcup_{\substack{ad=n, a>0}}  \bigcup_{b \mod d}K \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ & d \end{array} \right)$$

I would like to know the volumes of $T(n)$. So here are my questions:

> 1. is there a similar standard decomposition in left cosets?
> 2. can we directly compute the measure (for a fixed left Haar measure on $G$) of the right cosets?

Comment: For 1, the first definition is manifestly invariant under transpose (if $K$ is the standard maximal compact subgroup) so you can just take the transpose of the second definition, which gives a right coset description. For 2, for $GL_2$, left and right Haar measure are the same so all cosets should have the same measure.

Comment: What is $F$?  (And then some more characters.)